# How to include Dynamic image filenames in word and re-reference them

Tags: ms-word, dynamic-text

Is it possible to include filenames for images inserted into word that can be dynamically re-used throughout the document?

For example:
[See word screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbdkP.jpg)

In the screenshot i have inserted images from PPT by exporting the PPT as Jpegs and inserted them individually into cells in a table in word. These images are then referenced throughout the instructional text in red text. If ever i delete a slide i have to go through the entire document to change the numbers appropriately. I want some sort of dynamic text to reduce my work efforts during client amends. Possible?

Comment: Probably, althuogh it's not clear exactly what you're asking. I don't see what the file names have to do with referncing a number "Slide 1". In any case, this is not a programming quesetion and therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow. It belongs on an end-user site like Super User or Microsoft Answers.

Comment: Thanks, i'll redirect the question there

Answer (score 0):

If you use Word's captioning tool for the Slide numbering, you can achieve the results you want by cross-referencing the captions. If you insert/delete a slide and refresh the content via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, the cross-references will update accordingly.